# Add envMap to model.json materials

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, mapping, blender

I have exported an object with blender to .json format for display with three.js, all goes well, I added manually all the maps to the exported file (not included by the exporter but once mapped well in blender added easily manually)

**model.json:**

```
"materials":[{
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "DbgIndex":0,
    "DbgName":"FrontCol",
    "blending":"NormalBlending",
    "shading":"phong",
    "colorDiffuse":[1.0,1.0,1.0],
    "mapDiffuse" : "model_d.png",
    "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
    "colorSpecular":[0.8,0.4,0.0],
    "mapSpecular" : "model_s.jpg",
    "mapBump" : "model_b.jpg",
    "mapBumpScale" : 4
}
```

I need to apply an environmap for richer reflections, normally easily defined with three.js and added

**index.html:**

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    envMap: mapEnvironment
} );
```

Can this be done? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling with something similar, and while I am unable to load it in JSON directly, workaround here is assigning it for all meshes during import. Then, based on your material reflectivity you'll see it on a material, or not:

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load( "file.json" , function ( obj ) {
    obj.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {    

            child.material.envMap = mapEnvironment;

                        }
    });
```

This keeps your material properties from JSON, just adds this property on top.

edit: Here's the version for the JSONLoader:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'file.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
    for ( var k in materials ) {
        materials[k].envMap = mapEnvironment;    
    }

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
    scene.add( mesh );
});
```

Comment: I tried on the fly, I use THREE.JSONLoader and with that I could not get it to work, neither using THREE.ObjectLoader and again your code (it breaks the rendering) ... I'm still in the beginning ...

Comment: ok here it is with JSON loader. I wasn't sure what loader you are using.

Comment: `var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'file.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {

     for ( var k in materials ) {

      materials[k].skinning.envMap = mapEnvironment;

     }

     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
    
     

     scene.add( mesh );

     

    });`

Comment: please disregard the comment and check answer edit (bad formatting and error, no idea how to edit). I'm very new here.

Comment: not new with three.js !! great, where do you get these snippets, I always feel quite stupid, three has a huge library and I can't find these little things ... (ps please vote my question, that valorizes also your answer)

Comment: this is from three.js examples, I think I copied loader from simple skinning example and just added the material env map part. But generally if you just look at couple of examples you can somehow put together what you are looking for :) good luck